# Better way to cancel “hammer beating wall” noise

Tags: acoustics

I live very near a bulding contruction site, so the "hammer beating wall" noise is a constant in my daylife for the next one year and half (when the building construction will be finished).

In order to cancel the hammer noise, I use a 40 mm headphone with fan noise playing in medium to high volume (I mean, not low volume, but not maximum volume). (My headset doesn't have noise-canceling feature by the way.)

I ask:

1 - Based on Acoustics Science, is this the best way to cancel a "hammer beating wall" noise?

2 - Is there any other frequency, or combinations of frequencies, which I could build using a software, which would be the perfect match for canceling hammer noise? I mean, even better than fan noise frequencies?

Hearing a loud fan noise with headphones is not that nice thing, but is way better than the hammer. It cancels the hammer noise (I hear nothing, but I feel the floor vibrating a bit). So I am searching for the ultimate sound for cancelling the hammer beating wall noise.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word best can be subjective and is dependent on how much money you want to spend and what you can practically do with the technology available.

You're current strategy of listening to white noise via headphones at a volume so that it masks the noise of construction is not a good strategy because the volume of noise emitted by your headphones could be [damaging your hearing system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noise-induced_hearing_loss) and it could be causing you permanent [hearing loss](https://www.nidcd.nih.gov/health/noise-induced-hearing-loss). You need a system that will [protect you hearing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hearing_protection_device).

### Ear Plugs and Ear Muffs - Passive Noise Reduction

The first thing you could do is wear [ear plugs](https://www.3m.com.au/3M/en_AU/company-au/all-3m-products/%7E/All-3M-Products/Personal-Protective-Equipment/Hearing-Protection/Safety/Personal-Safety/Ear-Plugs/?N=5002385%208709322%208711017%208711405%208720539%208720546%208720869%203294857444&rt=r3) or [ear muffs](https://www.3m.com.au/3M/en_AU/company-au/all-3m-products/%7E/All-3M-Products/Personal-Protective-Equipment/Hearing-Protection/Safety/Earmuffs/?N=5002385%208709322%208711017%208720539%208720546%208720749%203294857444&rt=r3). These will reduce noise but not eliminate it.

Some issues with ear plugs are:

- some people find them uncomfortable to wear for prolonged periods.
- people with ear drum damage or ear infections cannot use them.
- to be effective, the plugs must be inserted correctly, with most of
  the plug inserted within the ear canal.
- for hygiene reasons, most ear plugs are disposable and should only be
  worn once.
- ear plugs made of rubber and *fitted to you ears by a professional auditory expert* can be reused, but they must be washed very carefully between each time they are used.
- they muffle all sounds, including the sounds in the room were you
  are, so they make conversations and listening to music or other
  sounds difficult. This also applies to ear muffs.

Some issues with ear muffs are:

- each muff must completely cover each ear
- the muffs must be periodically cleaned, preferably with antibacterial
  wipes, for hygiene reasons and to prevent ear infections.
- ear muffs can be uncomfortable to wear for prolonged periods, but
  generally are more comfortable than ear plugs.
- the muffs must be worn so there is no air gap between the muff and
  the ear or sides of the head.
- for *slightly* increased noise reduction, ear plugs can be worn while
  using ear muffs.

Some people, such as underground miners in some countries, must wear either ear plugs or muffs, or both, for the entire 12 hour duration of their working shift. Because of this, it is possible to wear either ear plugs or muffs constantly while you are at home, but it would not be an ideal situation. While sleeping it is possible to sleep with ear plugs inserted in ones ears, but it would be very difficult to sleep with ear muffs on. Which would be a problem for people who work night shift and must sleep during the day.

### Active Noise Reduction

Noise cancelling headphones could offer a solution, but they are best at cancelling constant noise that has a limited frequency range, such as that produced by vehicle engines. They work by producing a sound with the same frequency as the disturbing noise but out of phase so the two sounds cancel each other.

With noise cancelling headphones it would be best to use headphones that surround each ear. The issues that I listed for ear muffs also apply to noise reduction headphones.

It may be possible to purchase a noise reduction system that could be [installed in a room](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/07/11/science/windows-street-noise.html), but such a system would at best reduce noise in that [room](https://www.extremetech.com/extreme/170649-sono-a-noise-cancelation-and-isolation-device-that-sticks-on-your-window).

### Alterations to the House or Apartment

These [options](https://soundproofnation.com/noise-canceling-system-for-home/) [may be expensive](https://soundproofliving.com/home-noise-canceling-system/) and may or may not be practical in your situation.

- Seal and thicken the doors (replace the door with one made of dense
  timber). Use a door sweep at the bottom of the door to disrupt the
  gap between the base of the door and the floor.
- Seal the windows and cover the windows with heavy drapes. The drapes act as a sound insulator.
- Add mass to the walls. This can include retrofitting sound proofing
  insulation, which would be very expensive to do or you can hang
  drapes or carpets on the walls.
- Soundproof the ceiling and floor by installing sound proofing
  insulation above the ceiling and below the floor.
- If possible erect a noise barrier between the source of the noise and
  your dwelling.

Comment: Hello, Fred. Thank you for the answer. I think my best solution at hand is to use earplugs (which I already do, I forgot to mention) plus a noise cancelling headphones (which I will have to buy), and stick the volume (of the music/sound that is playing) to the minimum possible. A last help is going to build a digital sound with the perfect frequencies in order to decrease the chances of getting a hear damage (I don't know if it does make sense though, I mean, pick up the right frequencies that is more "ear-friendly"...)

Comment: You might be able to buy such a system. I know they have been made for industrial uses - trucks & cars. I just don't know a useful system has been made for domestic situations. I would be easier than making one, but if you do you might be able to patent it. Good luck!

Comment: LOL. Yes, it would be nice to have such a domestic system available at amazon, for example.

Comment: I kinda doubt that an active noise control system for domestic use used to cancel noise from all transmitting elements (believe me this may constitute every wall of the house) is a feasible solution. Apart from the very high complexity, I believe it would be rather expensive. Fred is right in that. you should patent such a system as it is going to be very complex. Two of the most common approaches are to reduce noise at the source (I doubt this is a solution here) or reduce noise at the listener (most probably more appropriate). For the latter Fred has suggested some nice alternatives.